# Number of triangles formed from a set of points

Tags: combinatorics

If points $A, B, C$ belong to line $l_1$ and points $M, N, H, Z$ belong to line $l_2$, then number of triangles can be drawn using the set of points  $A, B, C, M, N, H, Z$  equals $210$ or $30$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please show what you've tried for solving the question and also use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to type math :)

Comment: It is equal to 30. Hint: use combinations and exclude line cases

Comment: Can you help me I need steps

Comment: Hint: two of the three points of the triangle should be on one line and the  third point on the other line. First assume you need to pick two from $l_1$ and one from $l_2$ and the next case pick two from $l_2$ and one from $l_1$

Comment:  thanks a lot